# How do I prevent my bathtub hand valve from running?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, leaks

Faucet was installed in 2017, when house was built. It leaks when I open either the cold or hot water valves on the bathtub, I notice the leak begin once there's significant flow rate through the main tub. I thought it was a valve not seating on the faucet hand itself, so I ordered a new replacement from Delta, and the replacement did the exact same thing. I have taken apart the connection and see no issue with the seals, the leak is coming from the outlet ports.  I've talked to some handy friends, and they are telling me the only way to fix it is to remove the tile, or access from the bottom side of the floor (Punch a whole in the sheet rock on the ceiling of first floor). I'm reaching out here to see if there is some other way to solve this.

[image: Bath Set Up]

[image: Bath Faucet Leaking from 4 black ports]

Comment: Would check the other side of the wall.  If very lucky and have a fairly godmother, might find an access door for repairs.  If choice between drywall and tile to rip out, will choose drywall every time.

Comment: Where is the faucet you're talking about?

Comment: You mean the shower head dribbles when the bath is running? Mine does that a bit & after taking the whole thing apart discovered it's a design fault - there's no actual rubber seal on the 'swap over' valve, it's just metal to metal.

Comment: I don't know how exactly the OP's faucet functions, but in my case I have to pull the swap over lever upward real hard to make the faucet stop when the shower starts.

Comment: As the comments suggest, please clarify which item is "leaking," and by "leak" do you mean dribbling at its output or losing water into the wall or floor.

Comment: You're experiencing a leak in the "hand shower" part of the faucet, including in a brand new unit purchased directly from Delta. I would suspect that the issue is in the cutoff valve that directs water to the main tub spout or to the handheld wand. (Vote to reopen after the edit)

Comment: @FreeMan How would I go about changing the cutoff valve?

Comment: are you sure you dont have a strong pressure of water causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing a leak in the "hand shower" part of the faucet, including in a brand new unit purchased directly from Delta. I would suspect that the issue is in the diverter that directs water to the main tub spout or to the handheld wand. It's likely that whatever seals the diverter isn't quite sealing like it should any more and that's allowing some water to trickle through the hose and into the hand shower.

Replacing the o-rings/washers/cartridges, whatever in the diverter *should* be a fairly straightforward process. I just did all the valves in our tub after a leak developed for the first time after 30 years. The hardest part was finding a matching o-ring from the dozens that were available at my local big-box store.

For mine, it was a simple matter of turning off the water, popping the plastic cap off the handle, unscrewing the handle and pulling parts out of the faucet behind the wall. That got me to the o-rings and I was able to remove & replace them, then reassemble.

For yours, well, we can't see enough details of the faucet to offer suggestions on how to disassemble the diverter, but since you know it's a Delta, and you know the model number, you should be able to find the installation/repair instructions online, and that will tell you exactly how to disassemble it and what you need to replace to prevent it from leaking.

If you were to provide the model number in your question, I'm sure someone here could do the searching for you, but hey, it's a Do-It-*Yourself* site, not a "Here, let me Google that for you" site, so I'm sure you'll do just fine. ;)